# Streaming CameraImages to a Widget

Tags: flutter, camera

I'm trying to use the Camera package of flutter to produce a stream of CameraImage objects and then subscribe to them with a StreamBuilder.

```
Widget streamBuilder = StreamBuilder<StreamedInferencedImage>(
    stream: inferencedImageStream,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<StreamedInferencedImage> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Container();
      } else {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Container();
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Container();
          case ConnectionState.done:
            return Container();
          case ConnectionState.active:
            final data = snapshot.data;
            if (data == null) {
              return Container();
            }

            return Image.memory(data.cameraImage.planes[0].bytes);
        }
      }
    });
```

This is the error I'm seeing:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:5718:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:5574:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodec (dart:ui/painting.dart:2056:60)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

If anyone knows the right way to do this, I'd really like some information. Everyone seems to just use the Camera Preview button, but in my case, I'd like to view it with some image augmentation, so it needs to be in sync even with the cost of a slight latency.

Comment: Can you check the image format you are trying to pass to `Image.memory` constructor? (This constructor needs a compressed image format.)

Comment: @PeterKoltai I'm encoding as JPG with full quality, can try lowering